# Access a parent from within an event method

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, datepicker, parent-child

I'm trying to add a button to the .net 4.0 DatePicker calendar, and I have the button in place, but can't figure out how to give it access to the calendar.  The guide I'm using does it through using the this reference within the _Click method, but when I do it 'this' refers to the button rather than the calendar.  So my thought was to use GetParent and then GetChild to get a reference to the calendar.  But GetParent is not available to me off of 'this'.  Any ideas?

Thanks

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerCalendarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Calendar}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                              Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}" />
                                <Button x:Name="PART_TodayButton"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Margin="10,0,10,2"
                                        Content="Today"
                                        Click="PART_TodayButton_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [VisualTreeHelper Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx), specifically the `GetParent` method

Since the calendar is a parent of your button, you won't need to go up in the tree and then down again, so you should not use `GetChild`

Comment: The calendar is the parent?  I thought the stackpanel was, this makes it a whole lot easier :)

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase the calendar is an ancestor of the button. So you would call `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` in a loop until you get the calendar

Answer (score 0):

in the arguments of your click handler you have the 'sender' (Object) : this is from the sender that you want to find the parent with the VisualTreeHelper class.